Error: Error during blog generation: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
I am trying to request from an end-point deployed on firebase cloud functions, the endpoint basically uses perplexity API to generate a response then send it to the client.
cloud functions: uses axios post to the perplex api setting the auth with bearer api and app/json
Frontend Client:
fetch with a method POST using the function url and body: JSON.Stringify.......
I kept getting cannot set headers after sent to client and a axios 400. Not sure what's going on..
the code supposes to send the response to the client in json format.

Without seeing code, we can't help you.  It's required on Stack Overflow to provide a complete minimal reproducible example so we can see what you might be doing wrong and suggest a change.
